# Find the extrema of a linear form on a unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, compactness

Let $ T: \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R $ such that $ T(X)= a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + .....a_px_p$ with  ${A_v} = (a_1,a_2,...a_p) \in \mathbb R^p. $

Let $E =\{ X \in \mathbb R^p : \sum_{i=1}^{p} \frac{x_i^2}{\alpha_i^2} \leq 1\}$

1) Find $T(E)$

Using Lagrange Multipliers I have a maximization problem of $a_1x_1/\alpha_1 +a_2x_2/\alpha_2 + ... a_px_p/\alpha_p $ subject to  $\sum_{i=1}^{p} \frac{x_i^2}{\alpha_i^2} \leq 1$ From where I obtain that $X_n = \frac{\alpha_n a_n}{2}$

2) Find $x_*$ and $x^*$ such that $ T(x^*) = \sup T$ and $T(x_*) = \inf T$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I have added an edit for the first part

Comment: How do you justify these inequalities? Plus, it seems unlikely that the answer doesn't depend on the $\alpha_i $.

Comment: The first one goes by the absolute value definition, the secondo due to the property of sums and the las one due to the hypothesis.

Comment: I have also tried max $ a_1x_1 +a_2x_2 +.....a_px_p $  subject to $\sum_{i=1}^{p} \frac{x_i^2}{\alpha_i^2} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Lagrange multipliers we obtain that $X_n = (\alpha_n*A_n)/2$ 
From there we obtain that if we take $K= \sqrt(\sum_{i=1}^p \frac{\alpha_i^2 A_i^2}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt(\sum_{i=1}^p{\alpha_i^2 A_i^2}}{2}$

From there we have that T(E) $\subset$ [-K,K]
We show the inverse contention by setting $-x_* = x^* = (\frac{A_v}{2\alpha_v^2(4)})$

Using that, we obtain that $T(x_*)= -K ; T(x^*) = K $ Which implies $[-K,K] \subset T(E)$

T(E) = [-K,K]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: do the change of variables $$ x'_i=\frac {x_i}{\alpha_i}$$
$ E $ becomes an honest (symmetric!) unit ball.